# Two gateways on the same network (10.12.15.20 and 10.12.15.21) - is there a way to combine them into single bonded internet connection?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have two gateways to internet on the same network. Ubuntu is installed on server with only one ethernet card. Is there a way to create a bonding of this two gateways from the same network where I have only one ethernet card? I was trying to add virtual ethernet alias ("auto eth0:1") but it is not being recognised in bonding configuration which I've found here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding.

Any ideas?

Regards